# Snowflake - Loading Pipe Delimited CSV File in Internal Stage into Table - Using COPY INTO - Numeric value '0xFF0xFE10x00' is not recognized

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm new to Snowflake,

I have created a table using DDL into a database called STOCKS_EOD and schema STOCKS

```
CREATE TABLE DIM_COMPANY_STOCK(
    COMPANY_STOCK_SK int NOT NULL,
    STOCK_TICKER STRING NOT NULL,
    SECTOR STRING NOT NULL,
    INDUSTRY STRING NOT NULL,
    COMPANY_NAME STRING NULL
);

create or replace file format csvformat
  type = 'CSV'
  field_delimiter = '|';
```

Trying to load a staged file into table using the command, results in error : Numeric value '0xFF0xFE10x00' is not recognized

```
copy into STOCKS_EOD.STOCKS.DIM_COMP_STOCK
  from @fileLanding/DIM_COMPANY_STOCK_Export_All.csv.gz
  file_format = (format_name = csvformat)
  on_error = 'skip_file';
```

Sample Data:
1|A|CAPITAL GOODS|ELECTRICAL PRODUCTS|AGILENT TECHNOLOGIES
2|AA|CAPITAL GOODS|METAL FABRICATIONS|ALCOA CORP
3|AAN|TECHNOLOGY|DIVERSIFIED COMMERCIAL SERVICES|AARON'S INC

Comment: what happens if you import a file with only one row, the row in the example? what if the file is not compressed?

Comment: That error makes it look like you might have a UNICODE character in your data somewhere that is causing issues.  Can you confirm there is no special characters in your file?

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction @Felipe Hoffa and Mike Walton. After quite a lot of struggle, I now know the problem, I had exported data from SQL Server database running in Windows10, trouble is this process adds some random unknown special character to the start of each record. When I copied the three records in this post into a csv file and loaded into snowflake it worked. But I tried all possible options to export without that special character in the start of each record, but could not find a way. So at the moment, I export the records into csv

Comment: Then I save the content of this csv in a word file, then copy the contents of this word file into a new csv and load into snowflake table, only then it works

Comment: can you share one sample file?